# Trace of a product in finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ be a finite field of cardinal $p^n$. We choose an arbitary generator $t$ of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ such that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, then any element $a$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ can be written as $a_0+a_1t+...+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}$.

For any two elements $a,b$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, Then I want to ask if we can prove $\operatorname{tr}(ab)=\sum_0^{n-1}a_ib_i$.

Thanks.

Comment: No, take $p=3,t = 1+\sqrt2, n=2, a=1,b=t, tr(t) =  ( 1+\sqrt2)+( 1-\sqrt2)=2$

Comment: @reuns Thanks for your counterexample.

Comment: In fact it is never true if $n\not\equiv 1\bmod p$, take $a,b\in \Bbb{F}_p, tr(ab)=n ab$.

Comment: What @reuns said. However, the question about the existence of so called *trace-orthonormal bases* on a finite field is interesting. I don't remember the details, but if you can find a basis of $\{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n\}$ of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}/\Bbb{F}_p$ such that $tr(t_it_j)=\delta_{ij}$, then the bilinear form given by the trace does take the prescribed form. But, this requires a careful choice of basis. A random monomial basis won't do.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen (in characteristic not 2) $tr(ab)$ is given by $q(x)=tr((\sum_j x_j t^j)^2)$ and every quadratic form is equivalent to a sum of squares $q(Mx)=\sum_j c_j x_j^2$ for some $M\in GL_n(\Bbb{F}_p)$ so we have to check if the $c_j$ can all be squares